# System-wide Django package overrides virtualenv in mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django app on mod_wsgi 3.3 (Ubuntu 12.04). It doesn't work only because the (older) system-wide version of Django interferes and overrides the one installed in virtualenv. I've checked that **uninstalling the system-wide version fixes this**, but I want to have both.

Here's my configuration:

/home/user/project/wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project

```
WSGIScriptAlias /project /home/user/project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/user/project:/home/user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project

<Directory /home/user/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Here's what I see in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Fri Aug 01 16:02:09 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/user/project/wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
[Fri Aug 01 16:02:09 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Aug 01 16:02:09 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

This is because the global version is 1.3, which doesn't have django.core.wsgi.

The virtualenv version is 1.7. Under virtualenv, Python imports the correct Django version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not activating your virtualenv inside the wsgi file, so Python knows nothing about it.

Comment: I can't find any info on activating virtualenv from Python. I always do it from shell.

From what I've read, python-path parameter in WSGIDaemonProcess should be enough. And it works, unless old Django is installed globally.

Comment: I followed advice from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments with reordering sys.path and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

With the version of mod_wsgi you are using, you could have just said:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-home=/home/user/venv python-path=/home/user/project
```

That is, use python-home option to WSGIDaemonProcess to specify the sys.prefix value of the Python virtual environment.

No need to fiddle with sys.path in the WSGI script file.

Comment: No, it doesn't work (Apache fails to start). I really have mod-wsgi 3.3, I've checked.

Comment: My mistake, python-home was added in 3.4. Distros still use old versions. Latest is 4.2.X at the time.